# How to open a .NET 2.0 project in VS 2010 without converting?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

As soon as I open the project in VS1010, the wizard starts for upgrading to .net 4.0.  I need to keep these projects in .net 2.0 without migrating to .net 4.0.

Comment: Are you sure it is trying to convert to .net4? It is more likely trying to convert an old Visual Studio format to VS2010.

Comment: You are right - it is actually trying to convert to new VS2010 format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conversion is to support the changes in the newer IDE - not necessarily anything to do with changing the targeted framework.

Apparently this is called **round tripping** and is not currently supported:

[why does visual studio 2010 convert my projects](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/15/why-does-visual-studio-2010-convert-my-projects.aspx)

However, once converted you can re-target the framework back to version 2 under the project properties.

Comment: Thanks for the link - Looks like there is no way to open in VS2010 without converting the format as you mentioned, round tripping is not supported.

Answer (score 2):

VS2010 has a newer project file format than VS2005 so it needs to convert the project file itself.

But you can still target older framework versions with VS2010 just

right click project -> properties -> application tab and then you can select the target framework:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to keep the old VS format as well while opening the project in VS2010?

Comment: According to the [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/15/why-does-visual-studio-2010-convert-my-projects.aspx) posted by Martin it's not supported. You have to convert then you can retarget.

Answer (score 0):

well you can change the target framework.. this is not migration of framework but migration of project and it convert project defination only.

So you can progress with migration process and then change the target framework.. this will not have any bad impact on your project.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't changing framework version it's changing visual studio version. It will only matter if you want to open the converted solution in an earlier version of VS.

Basically it bogs with the xml in the solution and project files, so the new VS2010 IDE options work.

If you need to access them from an earlier version of VS, you are going tro be doing a bit of messing about, if the sln or prj files change, e.g. add a new class / project etc.